# Why open function forks when the given command is wrong?

Tags: perl, fork, ipc

In a Perl script, I want to execute a system command and write the output in the console. Here is a snippet who reproduce the behavior of my script:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

sub safe_run_cmd {
    my ($cmd) = @_;
    my $pid;
    my $sleep_count;
    my $fcmd;

    do {
        $pid = open($fcmd, "$cmd 2>&1 |");
        unless(defined $pid) {
            warn("Cannot fork: $!\n");
            die("Bailing out\n") if $sleep_count++ > 6;
            sleep(1);
        }
    } until (defined $pid);

    if($pid) {
        while ( my $line = <$fcmd> ) {
            print $line;
        }
        close $fcmd;
    } else {
        exit(0);
    }

    print("End safe_run_cmd\n");
}   

eval{safe_run_cmd("bad_command")};
print(`ps aux | egrep open`);

print("-----\n");

eval{safe_run_cmd("echo good_command")};
print(`ps aux | egrep open`);
```

I called the function *safe* because I follow what is described in the [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Safe-Pipe-Opens).

If I run my script, I get this:

```
pierre 146161 21.0  0.0  21916  4548 pts/1    S+   14:32   0:00 perl open.pl
pierre 146163  0.0  0.0  21916  2816 pts/1    S+   14:32   0:00 perl open.pl
pierre 146164  0.0  0.0   4320   756 pts/1    S+   14:32   0:00 sh -c ps aux | egrep open
pierre 146166  0.0  0.0  12752  1008 pts/1    S+   14:32   0:00 grep -E open
-----
good_command
End safe_run_cmd
pierre 146161 10.5  0.0  21916  4548 pts/1    S+   14:32   0:00 perl open.pl
pierre 146163  0.0  0.0  21916  3516 pts/1    S+   14:32   0:00 perl open.pl
pierre 146168  0.0  0.0   4320   756 pts/1    S+   14:32   0:00 sh -c ps aux | egrep open
pierre 146170  0.0  0.0  12752   996 pts/1    S+   14:32   0:00 grep -E open
End safe_run_cmd
pierre 146161 10.5  0.0  21916  4744 pts/1    S+   14:32   0:00 perl open.pl
pierre 146171  0.0  0.0   4320   708 pts/1    S+   14:32   0:00 sh -c ps aux | egrep open
pierre 146173  0.0  0.0  12752  1008 pts/1    S+   14:32   0:00 grep -E open
-----
good_command
End safe_run_cmd
pierre 146161 10.5  0.0  21916  4744 pts/1    S+   14:32   0:00 perl open.pl
pierre 146175  0.0  0.0   4320   788 pts/1    S+   14:32   0:00 sh -c ps aux | egrep open
pierre 146177  0.0  0.0  12752  1012 pts/1    S+   14:32   0:00 grep -E open
```

We can see, when I print the list of the processes after running the bad command, I have two perl forks. When the first one ends, the second one continue from the call of `open`. But, when the command is right, `open` doesn't fork.

What can I do to avoid this fork (or to manage it) and to display an error message when the command is bad?

Comment: I don't see what is _safe_ about your `run_cmd` function vis-a-vis the perl docs you reference.  Those are specifically discussing the special construct of opening `"|-"` and `"-|"`, neither of which is what you are doing.  Please see [`perlsec`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html) for a discussion of untrusted/tainted inputs (e.g., your `$cmd`).

Comment: @pilcrow `open($fcmd, "$cmd 2>&1 |")` is equivalent to `open($fcmd, "-|", "$cmd 2>&1")`. See https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html.

Comment: Thanks, @Pierre.  It's my understanding that the _safety_ referenced has to do primarily with avoiding shell parsing of (possibly [tainted](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Taint-mode)) command arguments, by controlling precisely what the child does or exec()s.  (Also, `open($fh, $mode, @list)`.) That seems to me to apply here.

Comment: I see that you found your answer on the account of what  `FATAL` does ... still, a comment: the `open` has to fork, how else would it run another process? And it can't know whether that new process is fine or not before that gets run.  Also note that here a shell will be started (to get that `2>&1` done) and I think that it, too, will fork to run the job.

Comment: Note: there are a number of good modules for running (and controlling external commands), with control over standard streams as well.  In the order of increasing capability and complexity, see for example `Capture::Tiny`, `IPC::Run3`, `IPC::Run`.  Also note `IPC::System::Simple`

Comment: That "cannot fork" error message is wrong and misleading. `open -|` will also fail if the the child process has immediately exited because of execve(2) errors. Example: `perl -e '$SIG{CLD}=sub{warn "the child forked /me/\n"};open my $fh, "-|", "nope" or print "open failed\n"'`

Comment: And there's no way fork/clone could fail with `ENOENT` ("No such file or directory"). For anybody who may wonder, perl is [using a pipe](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/37e7f9c10d7c4b145b48133dcde5058d875bed7b:/doio.c#l2280) to transmit the execve errno from the parent to the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `warnings FATAL => 'all'` has a side-effect on the `open` function. Indeed, if `open` gets a warning, it immediately dies. So, if I remove it from the code, I get a correct output:

```
Cannot fork: No such file or directory
Cannot fork: No such file or directory
Cannot fork: No such file or directory
Cannot fork: No such file or directory
Cannot fork: No such file or directory
Cannot fork: No such file or directory
Cannot fork: No such file or directory
Cannot fork: No such file or directory
pierre 207725  2.3  0.0  21644  4432 pts/1    S+   15:28   0:00 perl open.pl
pierre 207750  0.0  0.0   4320   816 pts/1    S+   15:28   0:00 sh -c ps aux | egrep open
pierre 207752  0.0  0.0  12752   984 pts/1    S+   15:28   0:00 grep -E open
-----
good_command
End safe_run_cmd
pierre 207725  2.3  0.0  21644  4448 pts/1    S+   15:28   0:00 perl open.pl
pierre 207754  0.0  0.0   4320   748 pts/1    S+   15:28   0:00 sh -c ps aux | egrep open
pierre 207756  0.0  0.0  12752   996 pts/1    S+   15:28   0:00 grep -E open
```

To automaticly die if the command doesn't exist, it is possible to use [`autodie`](https://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) instead of the `do` block:

```
sub safe_run_cmd {
    my ($cmd) = @_;
    my $pid;
    my $sleep_count;
    my $fcmd;

    use autodie;
    $pid = open($fcmd, "$cmd 2>&1 |");

    while ( my $line = <$fcmd> ) {
        print $line;
    }
    close $fcmd;

    print("End safe_run_cmd\n");
}
```

I get:

```
pierre 211968 11.5  0.0  26544  7244 pts/1    S+   15:32   0:00 perl open.pl
pierre 211971  0.0  0.0   4320   768 pts/1    S+   15:32   0:00 sh -c ps aux | egrep open
pierre 211973  0.0  0.0  12752  1064 pts/1    S+   15:32   0:00 grep -E open
-----
good_command
End safe_run_cmd
pierre 211968 11.5  0.0  26544  7264 pts/1    S+   15:32   0:00 perl open.pl
pierre 211975  0.0  0.0   4320   792 pts/1    S+   15:32   0:00 sh -c ps aux | egrep open
pierre 211977  0.0  0.0  12752  1032 pts/1    S+   15:32   0:00 grep -E open
```